# How to assign column name to return value of scalar function in sql serve

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have defined a function in sql function, that inputs 3 names (three varchars) and outputs one name (one varchar)'. What I only want to is to give this return value a name/column name.

Right now when I call my function:

```
select concat_names(@first_name, @middle_name,@last_name)
```

I see returned varchar with **no column name**.

Here is complete code:

```
if object_id('[co1].[concat_names]') is not null
    drop function [co1].[concat_names];
go
create function [co1].[concat_names]
(
    @first_name varchar(20),
    @middle_name varchar(20),
    @last_name varchar(20)
)
returns varchar(62)
as
begin
    declare @full_name varchar(62)
    set @full_name = @first_name;
    if(@middle_name is not null)
    set @full_name = @full_name + ' ' + @middle_name;
    if(@last_name is not null)
    set @full_name = @full_name + ' ' + @last_name;
    return @full_name;
end
go
```

When I do:

```
select concat_names('A', 'B', 'C')
```

I get no column name in result set.
I know I can rename the column name after its returned as no column name in above select query.

What I only want to know, if there is any way I can name the column while returning the value from the

Comment: please give your function code and using code and result

Comment: Well, that is rename while calling the function. I want to give column name while returning the value

Comment: Since you are returning a final value as concated string you can simply add alias name with AS  when calling function.

select concat_names('A', 'B', 'C') AS 'Full Name' ;

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
select fullname(@fn, @mn,@ln) AS 'yourName'
```

You can create **table value** function to return column with name, like this exmple:

```
create function udf_ParseDate (
 @date as datetime
) returns @dateinfo table (
 id int identity(1,1),
 [date] datetime,
 [year] int,
 [month] smallint,
 [day] smallint
)
as
begin
 insert into @dateinfo
 select @date, YEAR(@date), MONTH(@date), DAY(@date)

 return;
end
```

In your code:

```
if object_id('[co1].[concat_names]') is not null
    drop function [co1].[concat_names];
go
create function [co1].[concat_names]
(
    @first_name varchar(20),
    @middle_name varchar(20),
    @last_name varchar(20)
)
returns returns @info table (
   fullName varchar(256)
)
as
begin
    declare @full_name varchar(62)
    set @full_name = @first_name;
    if(@middle_name is not null)
    set @full_name = @full_name + ' ' + @middle_name;
    if(@last_name is not null)
    set @full_name = @full_name + ' ' + @last_name;
    insert into @info select @full_name;
    return;
end
go
```

Comment: Well, that is rename while calling the function. I want to give column name while returning the value

Comment: I know, you can return table from UDT, but its efficiency is less than scalar ones, I am not asking much, just willing to give a return name ... while mentioning 'return varchar(62)' ... i just want use 'return varchar(62) as fullname' instead.

Comment: @Cellman your request impossible in sql server, function can be `scalar`  or `table value`

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
SELECT fullname(@fn, @mn,@ln) AS COLUM_NAME_YOU_WANT
```

Create your function something like this:

```
    create function concatall (
     @fn as TEXT, 
     @mn as TEXT,
     @ln as TEXT
    ) returns @merged table (
     [FullName] TEXT
    )
    as
    begin
     insert into @merged 
SELECT CONCAT(@fn , @mn , @ln)


     return;
    end
```

Comment: Well, that is rename while calling the function. I want to give column name while returning the value

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is not possible in SQL Server for Scalar valued Functions. Even the default SQL Server Scalar valued function return data with ***(No column name)***

For example

```
 select Checksum('somedata')
```

Output

```
    (No column name)
 ---------------------
    -1791257452
```

I am not sure why you want the column name to come from function if you can use alias name, what benifit you are getting?

**If you just want to know it is possible or not, in that case answer is "NO".**

Only option you have is to use alias name with `AS` like follwong.

```
SELECT fullname(@fn, @mn,@ln) AS FullName
```

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, thank you!
I needed it for better documentation. While creating my diagrams, I wanted to give a relevant name to return value, so wanted the same return value name get mentioned in real SQL script as well.

Comment: I did helped that I cannot be helped :D